# linux proc folder

Tags: linux

am trying to get some info on the process space(pseudo filesystem) in linux.

Am finding few process being stucked up for long times in my server (its ok)
but when i checked the proc folder corresponding to that process i found following info and was quite interesting to find (data in bold)
**lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:11 exe -> /usr/local/bin/geneliaTesting (deleted)**

```
dr-xr-xr-x 2 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:19 attr
-r-------- 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:19 auxv
-r--r--r-- 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:24 cmdline
-rw-r--r-- 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:19 coredump_filter
-r--r--r-- 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:19 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:11 cwd -> /home8
-r-------- 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:19 environ
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:11 exe -> /usr/local/bin/geneliaTesting (deleted)
dr-x------ 2 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:11 fd
-r--r--r-- 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:19 io
-r-------- 1 rmail rmail 0 Aug  1 16:19 limits
 .....   and some other info.
```

The binary exists and is being used continuously by other processes as well...
Anyone any idea??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This a process running, whose executable has been deleted from the storage device while it was running.

Comment: No, *a* binary exists, with the same name as the binary that were used to run this program. However, the original executable file has been deleted - and replaced with a new copy with the same name, which or may not be identical file content wise.

Answer (score 0):

try using lsof .. pipe to less so you can read thru it... but this will list all open files/sockets (-n to remove name resolution which makes this command take a long time to complete on network socket reverse DNS etc)

```
lsof -n | less
```

you can then probably search for your process

if you see the deleted part .. it probably could be true but still running because something has the inode open

if you find the process ID (pid) you could look inside

```
ls /proc/PID_NUMBER/fd/
```

if you do see it in there you could very well pull a copy out of it

```
cp /proc/PID_NUMBER/fd/FD_NUMBER /tmp/copy_of_that_in_memory_file
```

then you can analyze it.. maybe try strings on it etc? determine the file type etc

file /tmp/copy_of_that_in_memory_file

use strings on it

```
strings /tmp/copy_of_that_in_memory_file | less
```

can't say I know what that is ...

strace can help you find out what its doing once you know the pid as well.. use -f to follow the children that open..

```
strace -fp PID_NUMBER
```